# Laravel best practice for with() method

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to know if there are ramifications of optimal joins in terms of joining via the view or when fetching the model itself.

So would this call:

`$deposit = Class::where('request_type', 1)->where('id', $id)->with(['customer', 'currencyTable', 'bankList', 'customerBank']);`

Be **totally** equivalent in terms of performance and other factors, as this return statement:

`return view('whatever.howEver.show', compact('oneVar', 'twoVar', 'etc'))->with(['customer', 'currencyTable', 'bankList', 'customerBank']);`

And if it is equivalent in terms of performance and so on, where do you place your `with()`?

Comment: aren't these two examples of `with()` totally different?

Comment: @ThijsSteel One uses with as part of the query builder, and the one is via the view yet the y both bring the same results, an instance of the model's relationship, hence my question. Please elaborate with an answer and be thorough, thanks.

Comment: do they both work?

Answer (score 0):

**First example**

```
$deposit = Class::where('request_type', 1)
->where('id', $id)->with(['customer', 'currencyTable', 'bankList', 'customerBank']);
```

You are querying for the `Class` model, and via `with()` you ask that it preloads the customer, currencyTable, ... relations defined in `Class`.

**Second example**

```
return view('whatever.howEver.show', compact('oneVar', 'twoVar', 'etc'))
->with(['customer', 'currencyTable', 'bankList', 'customerBank']);
```

This returns the given view, and gives the view access to the listed variables, similar to your usage of `compact`. This is not at all the same and does not query the relationship to my knowledge.

**Why they both work**

Laravel has something known as lazy loading. Even if you do not use `with()` as in the first example, you can still use the relationships, but the difference is that the relation is only queried when you access it, meaning multiple queries are done (usually slower).

Comment: So you are saying that "second example" returning the view `with()` eloquent makes the view load slower? Please be precise and explain how, since that is my main concern, thanks.

Comment: i'm saying the second example does something completely different. You should try it without the `with()` it will work

Comment: The `with()` from the first example makes it faster

Comment: Isn't it called eager loading (pre whatever)? I.e. not lazy loading (post whatever)

Comment: lazy loading is the reason why it works even without eager loading

Comment: Thanks for answer, i'll wait for other answers just to be sure, give it a week, if that's OK with you.